# Show a div when keyword is enter in search box

Tags: javascript, html, search

Basically what I want to do is show a div if a keyword has been entered in the search box. For example I type "Television" into the box and it will show a div an ID of Television, but I want to do this for about 5 results. Is this possible to be done with Javascript?

This is all I've got:

HTML:

```
<form class="pure-form">
<legend></legend>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example: Television" class="pure-input-rounded">
<button type="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv()" class="pure-button">Search</button>
```

```
<div id="noresults"  style="display:none; font:'proxima-nova'; color:#BA2E31;" class="results" >No Results were found! :(</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "block";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LnjR/)

[Live site](http://penguin.baileywhite.vacau.com/browse.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onkeypress attribute to compare your text box value with predefined strings.

```
<form class="pure-form">
<legend></legend>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example: Television" class="pure-input-rounded" onkeypress="checkMatch(this)">
<button type="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv()" class="pure-button">Search</button>

function checkMatch(obj) {
    /* get obj text and compare is to some other string */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. your code would look something like this:

```
<form class="pure-form">
    <legend></legend>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example: Television" class="pure-input-rounded" onkeyup="showDiv(this.value)">
<button type="button" name="answer" class="pure-button">Search</button>
</form> <script>
function showDiv(value) {
if (value.charAt(value.length - 1) == ' ')
   document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "block";
else 
    document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
<div id="noresults"  style="display:none; font:'proxima-nova'; color:#BA2E31;" class="results" >No Results were found! :(</div>
```

Comment: @AlexandruNedlcu When I enter this and enter for example television it doesn't show the div television? Is there something I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

So, as Tsikon has already answered You need to have an event defined for your text field and a JS function associated (showdiv()) with it
For eg: Onkeypress/Onchange and length of the field >0 
You can probably think of displaying the div only when atleast 3 characters are entered by when you probably know what to display in div.

Comment: oninput is good for validation because it captures click/key/paste/cut/drop events in one fell swoop...